# Rename file on dropzone.js with user ID on meteor app

Tags: javascript, meteor, dropzone.js

I have a meteor application with the plugin [dropzone.js](https://github.com/devonbarrett/meteor-dropzone). I want to save the images from the dropzone with the ID of the current user and the file name. But I don't know how to add the user ID in front of the file name. I can rename the file with

```
    getFileName: function(file, formData) {
        return 'some text' + file.name;
    }
```

My server file is :

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    UploadServer.init({
    tmpDir: process.env.PWD + '/public/uploads',
    uploadDir: process.env.PWD + '/public/uploads',
    checkCreateDirectories: true,
    uploadUrl: '/upload',
    // *** For renaming files on server
    getFileName: function(file, formData) {
        return file.fileName + file.name;
    }
  });
});
```

But, if I try to get the user ID with Meteor.userId() or this.userId, this doesn't work because I'm in a server side file.
So, do you know how I could pass the user ID on a server side file ?

Answer (score 0):

Import the meteor object into the file where you want the userId and then just use `Meteor.userId()`. *Never* pass the userId from the client.

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(function () {
  UploadServer.init({
    tmpDir: process.env.PWD + '/public/uploads',
    uploadDir: process.env.PWD + '/public/uploads',
    checkCreateDirectories: true,
    uploadUrl: '/upload',

    // *** For renaming files on server
    getFileName: function(file, formData) {
        return Meteor.userId() + file.fileName;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The import in my file on the server side doesn't work

Comment: If it doesn't then you have other problems. What version of Meteor are you using?

Comment: I use the version 1.4.2.7 of Meteor

Comment: So, I succeeded to pass the user ID on the server file by creating a publication on client side `Meteor.publish(null, function() {CurrentUserId = this.userId;
});` and using the "currentUserId" on server file. Thanks for your help !